# How to decode resource data in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, resources, decode

Is there a way to decode `qt_resource_data`?

```
\x9b\x99\x33\xf7\xf2\x3d\x35\xd2\xdc\x73\xef\xef\x37\xdf\xdf\xf9\
\xdc\x73\xce\xef\x9c\x3b\x93\x25\x22\x3f\x62\xaf\x5f\xb1\x57\x24\
\xf6\x62\xa1\x02\x54\x20\x1c\x0a\x44\x63\x6e\xfe\xcc\x8a\xfd\xb9\
\x23\xbc\xe1\x88\x18\xbd\xa4\x02\x71\x0a\x44\x01\xf0\x07\x65\xa1\
\x02\x54\x20\x9c\x0a\x10\xe0\x70\xc6\x8d\x5e\x53\x01\xa5\x00\x01\
```

Comment: Import the python module containing the data and read all the files with [QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html). If you don't know the names of the files it contains, list them with [QDirIterator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html). I assume you no longer have the original sources or the qrc file, right?